# $z$ component of angular momentum under Lorentz transformation for massless particle

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry, group-representations, helicity

This question is related  to this [Helicity states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497145/helicity-states/497202).

Suppose we have $k=[\omega,0,0,\omega]$.
 In Weinberg's book The Quantum Theory of Fields: Volume I he defines the state
$|k,\sigma\rangle$ as an eigenstate of the operator $J_{3}$ that is
\begin{equation}
J_{3}|k,\sigma\rangle=\sigma|k,\sigma\rangle
\end{equation}
where ${\mathbf{J }}=(J_1,J_2,J_3)$ are the rotation generators.
Since the 3 momentum and the 3 component of the angular momentum are pointing in the same direction this is a state of helecity $\sigma$.

Then he was able to show that under a Lorentz transformation, a massless particle  state should transform like this: 
$$U(\Lambda)|k,\sigma\rangle=e^{i\theta\sigma}| \Lambda k,\sigma\rangle.$$
Now before the Lorentz transformation we had 
$$J_3(|k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle)=|k\rangle\otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle=\sigma(|k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle)=\sigma|k,\sigma\rangle$$

Now after Lorentz transformation since parameter $\sigma$ does not change shouldn't we have
$$J_3(|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle)=|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle=\sigma(|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle)=\sigma|\Lambda k,\sigma\rangle$$
  ?

My main problem is this, if before the Lorentz transformation we had $ | k\rangle\ \otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle= |k\rangle\ \otimes \sigma|\sigma \rangle$ since under Lorentz transformation in the direct product state, only the momentum part change $$\Lambda(| k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle=e^{i\theta\sigma}|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle$$

and since $J_3$ acts only on the spin part, why
$$J_3(|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle)=|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle\neq \sigma(|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle)$$
?

Isn't this like saying that $J_3|\sigma \rangle=\sigma|\sigma \rangle$ and that $J_3|\sigma \rangle \neq \sigma|\sigma \rangle$?

Can anyone give  me a mathematical proof why $J_3|\Lambda k,\sigma\rangle \neq \sigma|\Lambda k,\sigma\rangle$?

Comment: After a general Lorentz transformation, the 3-momentum won't necessarily point along the z-axis as before. In that case, the first definition(as you have stated it) won't hold anymore for the transformed state.

Comment: what first definition? You mean that $J_3(|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle) \neq |\Lambda k\rangle\otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle$

Comment: As you have stated it, the definition of the state $|k,\sigma>$only holds for massless particles with momentum along z-axis right?

Comment: But why $J_3(|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle) \neq |\Lambda k\rangle\otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle$ ?

Comment: Remember that helicity is not equal to $J_{3}$, it is equal to the projection of $J$ along $p$. So $J_{3}|\sigma>=\sigma|\sigma>$ doesn't make sense in general. Replace $J_{3}$ by the helicity operator, and it is alright

Comment: Does that mean that $J_3$ act on the state  $|\Lambda k\rangle $ that is $J_3(|\Lambda k\rangle \otimes  |\sigma \rangle)= J_3|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle \neq |\Lambda k\rangle\otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97531/discussion-between-amilton-moreira-and-mani-jha).

Answer (score 4):

You have most definitions wrong. First of all,
$$
J_3|\vec k,\sigma\rangle=\sigma|\vec k,\sigma\rangle
$$
holds **only** when $\vec k\equiv \vec k_\star:=(0,0,\omega)$ is the **standard (reference) momentum** for massless particles. For other values $\vec k$ this equation is no longer true. For general $\vec k$, the state is defined (up to a normalisation factor that depends on conventions) as
$$
|\vec k,\sigma\rangle:=U(\Lambda)|\vec k_\star,\sigma\rangle
$$
where $\Lambda$ is, by definition, the standard Lorentz transformation that takes you from $\vec k_\star$ to $\vec k$:
$$
k\equiv\Lambda k_\star
$$

In general $|\vec k,\sigma\rangle$ is **not** an eigenstate of $J_3$, so your calculation is wrong. This is all standard material, and explained very clearly in the textbook.

Another important point that I'd like to stress is that the Poincaré Group is **not a direct product** (but a semi-direct product instead), and so the **reps do not factorise**:
$$
|\vec k,\sigma\rangle\neq |\vec k\rangle\otimes|\sigma\rangle
$$
This is yet another source of errors in your derivation.

With this in mind, what you want to prove is that the helicity of $|\vec k,\sigma\rangle$ is Lorentz invariant. In order to do so, you first have to define the helicity properly. The correct definition was given in a [previous question of yours](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494865/84967):
$$
h=\frac{\vec P\cdot\vec J}{|\vec P|}
$$

The proof that $h|\vec k,\sigma\rangle=\sigma|\vec k,\sigma\rangle$ is straightforward (cf. [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/408135/84967)). An even simpler proof is to note that $h$ is invariant under rotations, and so you can calculate it in a convenient frame or reference, the standard trick in any relativistic theory (lorentzian or otherwise). In the frame where $\vec k=\vec k_\star$, one has $h=J_3$, and so the claim follows.

Comment: My problem is if you start with a state  $ | k\rangle\ \otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle= |k\rangle\ \otimes \sigma|\sigma \rangle$ and if the sigma part does not change under Lorentz transformation  why $J_3(|\Lambda k\rangle\otimes |\sigma \rangle) \neq |\Lambda k\rangle\otimes J_3|\sigma \rangle$. My point is that $|\sigma \rangle$ part does not change under Lorentz transformation

Comment: @amiltonmoreira please see the updated version.

Comment: Can you give me any reference that explain me why Poincaré Group is not a direct product (but a semi-direct product instead), and so the reps do not factorize?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira For the Poincare group to be a direct product of the translation group and Lorentz group, the representation of its elements as translation and Lorentz transform $(T,\Lambda)$ would have to satisfy $(T_1,\Lambda_1)\cdot(T_2,\Lambda_2) = (T_1T_2,\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)$. However, [it does not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group#Poincar%C3%A9_group).

Comment: @amiltonmoreira see also e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poincar%C3%A9+group, together with the references in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41206/289977, if you want to get mathematical.

Comment: Are there any books other than Weinberg  that explains unitary representation of Poincare group?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira a standard reference is https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0611263

Comment: @amiltonmoreira you can read "quantum field theory and standard model" by Mathew Schwartz. The book includes a clear distinction between helicity spin and angular momentum and also an illuminating discussion on Lorentz and Poincaré group.